# Why the static variable doesn't work in other class?

Tags: java, android, static

I encountered a problem during do android project... I declared six variable in "A.java" as below.

```
public static int a = -1;
public static int b = -1;
public static int c = -1;
public static int d = -1;
public static int e = -1;
public static int f = -1;
```

I set that if readMessage equaled to s1..., then a = 0. And go on.
readMessage, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 and s6 are strings.

```
 if(readMessage.equals(s1)){
                   a=1;
                }
                else if(readMessage.equals(s2)){
                   b=1;
                }
                else if(readMessage.equals(s3) ){
                   c=1;
                }
                else if(readMessage.equals(s4)){

                   d=1;
                }
                else if(readMessage.equals(s5)){

                   e=1;
                }
                else if(readMessage.equals(s6)){
                   f=1;
                }
```

Now in MainActivity.java, I write codes as below. But it doesn't work! The images don't change.

```
ImgPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);

if((A.a) == 1){ImgPhoto.setImageResource(imgId[0]);}
    else if((A.b) == 1){ImgPhoto.setImageResource(imgId[1]);}
    else if((A.c) == 1){ImgPhoto.setImageResource(imgId[2]);}
    else if((A.d) == 1){ImgPhoto.setImageResource(imgId[3]);}
    else if((A.e) == 1){ImgPhoto.setImageResource(imgId[4]);}
    else if((A.f) == 1){ImgPhoto.setImageResource(imgId[5]);}
```

Can anyone help me? I searched on internet but I did't find any solution....
I will appreciate for your helps!

Comment: all your `a,b,c,d,...` are always 0, always. because they're 0 by default and you set them only to 0, try to init them with some value like -1 : `a=-1, b=-1, ...`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. So if I changed that  a = 1, b=1... it will work?

Comment: In general, declaring six variables like this is a bad idea. Define arrays instead, both for the ints and the `s` variables, and use loops.

Comment: @user6690200 Unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: @RinaChen Log the value of `A.a` before the `if` in your MainActivity. And also log the value of the `ImageResource and see if it is correct.`

Comment: The code now seems ok... I doubt `readMessage` equals any of  s1, s2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primitive data type **INT**‘s default value is 0.

You can see the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

So all of your fields A-F's value if 0.

Comment: On one condition, as class filed.

Comment: Yes, as Mr.user6690200 said. It's also showed in the oracle's doc.

Answer (score 0):

from [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.

so all `static` variables in `A.java` will set to `zero` or `null` by `jvm`
and the first if statement will always be true

the best Solution is to set them to unused value for example `-1`

```
public static int a=-1;
public static int b=-1;
public static int c=-1;
public static int d=-1;
public static int e=-1;
public static int f=-1;
```

Comment: have you tried to debug your code and see if the variables have changed ..?